# Yii2, ActiveQuery, subQuery have not entry with ID

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, relationships

I cannot found solution... We have mysql tables

```
`users`
id | username
1      Mike
2      John
3      Jane

`roles`
userID | roleID
1         2
1         3
3         1
```

So question is - I need select all users that have NOT specific roleID in one query. Also user can HAVE NOT any relations in roles (for example John have not any roleID so he should be selected in all queries).

Simple query is when user have some roleID (we can check it with ->joinWith()) - but I need invert this query, select all users that have any other except one roleID.

Problem is that we have oneToMany (users->roles) relations and Yii2 ->joinWith() is not working in correct way (as I think, I hope I'm wrong).

Can someone help to deal with it?

Comment: I don't completely understand the problem.I have given an answer on the assumption that you want to select all users who do not have any roles.Check it to see if that is what you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select all users who do not have any roles, then  simple SQL query to the above problem is

```
SELECT username 
FROM users 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT userID FROM roles)
```

The result will return "**john**" as he is not having any role

In Yii2, you can write the code to generate above query as

```
$subQuery=Roles::find()->select('userID ');

$query = Users::find()->
select("username")->where(['not in', 'id', $subQuery]);

$models=$query->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

If User model has 'roles' relation and $excludedRoleId is the roleId excluded, this returns Users without roles or Users which roles is not $excludedRoleId

```
User::find()
->joinWith(['roles'])
->where('roles.userID IS NULL OR roles.userID NOT IN ( SELECT userID FROM roles WHERE roleID = :roleId)', [':roleId' => $excludedRoleId])
->all();
```

Comment: Did you check it? `roles.roleID <> :roleId'` I think this condition will return another role... any another role except `:roleId`, isn't it? Example, one user have roleID 1,2,3 if we gonna check `roles.roleID <> 2` we still get roleID 1 or 3 and see the user (am I wrong?).

Im asking because I did the same - result is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood complete request. I've updated the code. Now it should work!